# Very bad TTFB time

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have Centos 7 server with Apache installed and in last two months our internal web page have really bad TTFB time. Is bad only on one page and not always (on every 3-4th click). We didn't change any settings after creating server year ago.
Web page is full of ajax, jquery and javascript.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

[Picture of TTFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRCUO.png)

Comment: Without a LOT MORE information this question is basically unanswerable

Comment: I don't know what data do you need. Tell me and I will give you.